# Mobile Safari window reports 980px

Tags: jquery, mobile

Why does this report 980 on the iPhone 4?  I thought it would be 960 or 640.

```
alert($(window).width());
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're getting the default viewport setting. See [Apple iOS docs - meta tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) and search for 'viewport'.

> **Property**  Description
>
> **width**    The width of the viewport in pixels. The default is 980. The range is from 200 to 10,000. You can also set this property to the constants described in “number.”
> Available in iOS 1.0 and later.

To get the device width, as per the docs:

> For example, to set the viewport width to the width of the device, add this to your HTML file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: thank you.  thanks also for the link to Applie iOS docs.  You're a lifesaver!

Comment: but if I set the viewport to width=device-width, shouldn't the ipad in landscape return 1024 ? Instead, it returns 768 (which is the height, not the width)

Comment: Solved a major problem I was having with responsive website design. Wasn't working on any device, tablet, android, ios at less than 980px. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
alert($(document).width());
```

Comment: I still get 980.  I would expect 640px since that is the horizontal width when held vertically.

Answer (score 0):

In safari the default the window width is 980px, so if your javascript begins executing before the window has loaded the the width will be 980px, even though your viewport meta tag specifies the width as 'device-width'.

If you find that adding the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` doesn't fix your problem, then make sure your Javascript code is executing only after the window has loaded.

In vanilla Javascript:

```
console.log(window.innerWidth) // might be the default width

window.onload= function () {
  console.log(window.innerWidth) // should now be device width
  //... your code here ...

}
```

Alternatively, if using jQuery:

```
console.log(window.innerWidth) // might be the default width

$( document ).ready(function () {
  console.log(window.innerWidth) // should now be device width
  //... your code here ...
})
```